# How to conditionally suppress exceptions to be sent to client from nestjs server?

Tags: nestjs, httpserver

I would like to suppress exceptions to be sent to client after the server sends data.

Here is the flow of steps:

- Client sends request for data;
- Request arrives at Controller and is processed by its service;
- Data if found is sent to client;
- If data not found or not authorized, Exception sent to client;
- DISALLOW EXCEPTIONS to be sent to client if they occur after the data was sent!!!
- Do cleanup, request logging, etc. work done on server - after data was sent;
- After cleanup work is done, ENABLE BACK EXCEPTIONS for next request;

I have setup an Exception filter and placed it in front of the Controller:

```
@UseFilters(HttpExceptionFilter)
@Get()
async queryDb(@Query() request_SqlParamsF: SqlParamsFolderI): Promise<MyEntity[]> { 
. . .
```

and here is the exception filter - reused from NestJs example doc. It catches the exceptions.

```
@Catch()
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();
    const status = exception.getStatus
      ? exception.getStatus()
      : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    const errorResponse = {
      code: status,
      timestamp: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
      path: request.url,
      method: request.method,
      message:
        status !== HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
          ? exception.name || exception.message || null
          : 'Internal server error',
    };

    Logger.error(
      `${request.method} ${request.url}`,
      exception.stack,
      'HttpExceptionFilter',
    );

    response.status(status).json(errorResponse);
  }
}
```

And here are couple of questions:

- how do you exactly stop the exception to go out to the client in the filter code ?
- what would be the mechanism to signal from the Controller (or its service) to the Exception filter when to allow the exceptions to the client (that is, before resulting data gets passed to client) and when to disallow them (after the data has been passed) ?

Comment: `response.json` (ExpressJS stuff) above is where you define the response that will be send to the client, so you can send anything regardless the exception thrown. This is how you don't propagate the error object itself to the client if you don't want to.

Comment: Would you know how to prevent sending anything? Just stop any propagation right there?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I arrived to this simple arrangement that appears to be working for those interested.

file: shared-values.ts

```
                          // public shared flag to allow/suppress propagation
                          // of exceptions to client in exception filter
                          // (YN = Yes/No)
export let YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient: boolean;

                          // function to set the shared flag value 
export const set_YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient = (yn: boolean) => {
  YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient = yn;
}
```

file: controller.ts

```
import {set_YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient } from ../shared-values.ts

@UseFilters(HttpExceptionFilter)
@Get()
async queryDb(@Query() request_SqlParamsF: SqlParamsFolderI): Promise<MyEntity[]> { 
                          // set flag to allow propagation
                          // of exceptions to client in exception filter
    set_YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient(false);
    . . .
    const data = getData( . . .) 
                          // delay cleanup work after data is sent
                          // about 1/2 second
    timer(500).subscribe(() => {

                          // set flag to suppress propagation
                          // of exceptions to client in exception filter
        set_YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient(true);
        do_cleanup_work();
        set_YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient(false);
    )
                          // sent data to client
    return data;

}
```

file: http-exception.filter.ts

```
import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  ArgumentsHost,
  Catch,
  Logger,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient } from './shared-values';

@Catch()
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {

  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {

    const ctx      = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request  = ctx.getRequest();
    const status   = exception.getStatus
                   ? exception.getStatus()
                   : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    Logger.error(
      `${request.method} ${request.url}`,
      exception.stack,
      'HttpExceptionFilter',
    );

    if (YN_StopHttpExceptionsToClient) {
                          // this changes the Exception status code to OK
                          // no message is sent to client
      response.status(HttpStatus.OK);

    } else {

      const errorResponse = {
        code: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
        path: request.url,
        method: request.method,
        message:
          status !== HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            ? exception.name || exception.message || null
            : 'Internal server error',
      };
      response.status(status).json(errorResponse);
    }

  }
}
```